# Laravel Blade variable scope

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am having trouble with variable scope in laravel blades when extending

home.blade.php (used by the controller):

```
@extends('templates.BaseBlade')

@section('head')
    <?php
    echo $testvar;
    ?>
```

BaseBlade.blade.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <?php
        $testvar = "this is a test";
    ?>
```

I was thinking that BaseBlade would be compiled, then $testvar should be accessible to home blade but this does not seem to happen in this order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So in laravel `Blade` templates, the scope of variable is passed from parents to children.

---

**Inheritance of Blade tempalte**

So if you start by returing a view like so:

```
return view('template-1')->with([
    'var1' => 'Test One',
    'var2' -> 'Test Two',
]);
```

In your blade template you can then echo these with the `{{ }}` syntax:

```
{{ $var1 }} # Test One
{{ $var2 }} # Test Two
```

Now say you are the using an `@include`, you will get both `var1` & `var2` in the scope and be able to override them an assign new variables to you include like so:

```
@include('_includes.include-1', ['var2' => 'Foo', 'var3' -> 'Bar'])
```

```
{{ $var1 }} # Test One
{{ $var2 }} # Foo
{{ $var3 }} # Bar
```

---

Now if you want to make a variable available to all blade templates which extend a given template (i.e. if "template-1" extends `app`). You can bind global variables in a `ServiceProvider` like so;

**BladeServiceProvider**

```
View::share('var4', 'Foo-Bar']);
```

Now you have access to `var4` in all of your templates

```
{{ $var1 }} # Test One
{{ $var2 }} # Test Two
{{ $var4 }} # Foo-Bar
```

Comment: please could you clarify where to user View::share

Comment: You can add it to any service provider but i would suggest ceating a `BladeServiceProvider` to help organise your code.

Comment: Can I use that in a blade - eg when a route simply returns a simple view

Comment: I would recommend reading the documentation on service providers as you will find it really useful (https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/providers). In short, the service providers are registered early in every request lifecycle and will be available to all of your routes and blade templates

Comment: It is behaving more like a constant instead of a variable

Answer (score 0):

Above answer is informative, hence selected as the accepted answer.
I have however found a simply solution, putting this at the top of /routes/web.php so its accessible to basic views (without controllers)
and all blades have the scope

```
\View::share([
    "myvariable1"=>"myValue1",
    "myvariable2"=>"myValue2";
]);
```

Comment: I'm glad you found my answer informative :). If you have a fairly simple project, I think your answer will work well. I would be cautious about doing this in a more complex application as it goes against the Single Responsibility Principle by mixing your routing with your template rendering

Answer (score -1):

if i understand the question right, you want to pass $variable from parent file to child file the answer of @Spholt is informative,
but you should know that when passing $variable to parent file the child file supposed to inherit that $variable with no changes.
but to just make sure we pass the $variable like @Spholt said.

Comment: Please expand your answer to avoid getting voted down, it does not give any additional info to the accepted answer, which is extremely concise and informative. You should improve on any existing answers, and not give a vague comment as an answer. Just a friendly suggestion