# Laravel: Can't use @include blade variable into its parent blade

Tags: php, laravel

I am facing a problem with the scope of the laravel blade file. The variable set inside the `@include` blade can't be used in its parent blade. For example

**child.blade.php**

```
$myVar = "foo";
```

And then in the **parent.blade.php**

```
@include('child') {{-- including the child blade. --}}
{{ $myVar }}   {{-- printing the child blade variable --}}
```

> Undefined variable: myVar in view parent.blade.php

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60754962/laravel-blade-variable-scope) solution but I  still can't modify the variable inside my child blade.

Answer (score 2):

Calling a variable in parent file which was initialized in child file, doesn't make sense.

What you can do is create the variable on parent blade file using and pass to child.

```php
@php($variable = 'test')
@include('child', ['variable' => $variable]) // Passing variable to child blade file.

{{ $variable }}
```

Comment: Basically, I want to modify the variable inside the child blade which is still not possible.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel if you want to access variable then you have to pass it into that function which will be in controller using compact()